# mysql and php security: database as catalog only

Tags: php, mysql, security, connection

I am using a mysql database only to display information. All of the information regarding security that I can find is in regard to dynamically creating usernames and passwords, or for the purpose of user input, which does not apply here, so forgive me if I missed a duplicate.

I am creating a separate php file for each of the following processes:

- config: contains the db host, username and password. this will be protected by htaccess
- opendb: This will login to the database
- closedb: This will exit the database
- functions: This will contain user defined functions

The username permissions will be limited to select only.

I am using prepared statements. Session start is contained within a user function.

Is there anything I'm missing? Does this sound relatively safe? Again, all of the info in this DB is *NOT* proprietary. The website is not large.

Please let me know if you need further information.

**UPDATE**

How necessary is it to use a salt?

Also, I read somewhere that you can put this into the ini file and just call a connection function without storing username and password. Is that a better option?

Comment: Depending on how exactly you implement it - it can be either safe or not

Comment: opendb and closedb should probably be in the same php file, as functions. Also, I cringe whenever someone names a file with functions "functions" (why not call your variables $variable? :-). They are database-related functions - call it db.php or somesuch...

Comment: Salt is only needed for lists of passwords, to avoid pre-computed brute-forcing. You do not need it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only bad scenario I can think of is that the database may be updated externally (out of your control). Someone adds javascript to fields you are displaying. Your website is then used as part of an XSS attack on your visitors. Solution: sanitize database outputs before display.

You may also want to avoid really expensive queries (to protect against denial of service), and make sure that your PHP and web-server are up-to-date.

Although it will be difficult to access your DB or pollute it from the outside, you should also cover yourself against more traditional attacks. For example, do not allow users to upload anything to an externally-addressable location (or not without making really sure that you know what is there).

Comment: How would someone update the database externally? How would they add javascript? The users cannot upload anything. The DB access is select only.

Comment: Externally as in "not through your application". This may or may not apply to your case. Will you be creating the data in the DB, or can you vouch for it? If not, then sanitize the bits before you display them.

Comment: My client is the only one adding to the db. Users of the site will need to connect to it so that the web page can display the data held within it. They will not add anything or update anything.

Comment: Your app, your call. I would sanitize anyway, but then again, I'm paranoid.

Comment: How would you do that if you were me? (What functions would you use?)

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/ (if the DB contains HTML), http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php (if it should not contain it).